# Excel formula that turns cells into empty cells if the cell next to it is already empty

Tags: excel, if-statement, is-empty

I need a formula in excel that turns the cells in column D empty if the corresponding cell in column C (i.e. on the same row) is already empty.

To elaborate, this is a sample from my excel sheet:

```
   C     D
1  0,5   500
2  0.3   400
3        600
4        700
5  3.1   400
6        350
7  1.1   400
```

I want it to turn into this:

```
   C     D
1  0,5   500
2  0.3   400
3        
4        
5  3.1   400
6        
7  1.1   400
```

All the values are hard coded. Is what I want possible?

Comment: You could put them in a new sheet (or different columns) with the cells made empty, then copy them back over the original data if you needed to. Otherwise to do it directly you would need VBA.

Comment: @TomSharpe How would I make the cells empty by putting them in a new sheet/different column?

Comment: You can use formula `=IF(C1="","",D1)` in some other column which is not used and then copy paste values in `Column D`, else you'll have to use VBA.

Comment: Great, the copying of cells using the if-formula worked. Thanks a whole lot!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you have in D1 to already create value etc.

But try:

```
=IF(C1="","", Your original value/formula here )
```

Comment: All the values in both columns are hard coded. I want to turn the hard coded cells in column D into blanks/empty if the cell next to it (in column C) is already empty

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by that, but the work sheet is exported from a data frame in R, so no cells contain formulas - just values.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure you can't use a formula in this case. What you need is a macro

```
Sub EmptyCells()
    For Counter = 1 To 20
        Set cell = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Counter, 2)
        If IsEmpty(cell.Value) = True Then
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Counter, 3).Value = ""
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

You can call the vba editor with alt+F11. Right click your sheet and select Insert->Module. Paste the code in there and save the excel as .xlsm file.
Open the macro view with alt+F8 and run your macro.

After you run the macro all values from column D that have an empty Value in column C will be empty too.